# Can Prolog make rules based on the facts available?

Tags: prolog, logic, artificial-intelligence

For example if there are facts of who likes which color and everyone likes green, but not everyone likes pink: `likes(X, green)` is true for all X, can Prolog somehow give a result that `likes(X, green)` is true for all X-es?

Lets say that there's also information about the gender of people within the rules in the form `female(deby). male(robert).` If according to the data set all females but not all males like pink, can Prolog return something like this: `likes(X, pink) :-female(X)`

**Edit**: When I say "I want to ask" in the last paragraph, I mean my query to Prolog should have this meaning.

To be clear I don't want to specify what Prolog should check. In English I don't want to ask, whether everyone likes green, but I want to ask: Can you make new rules based on the facts available?

facts:

```
male(albert).
male(brett).
female(chloe).
female(deby).

likes(albert, green).
likes(brett, green).
likes(chloe, green).
likes(deby, green).

likes(albert, pink).
likes(chloe, pink).
likes(deby, pink).
```

Comment: No, Prolog doesn't guess about your DB. Seems you need to search for 'ILP Prolog' and filter out among thousands of related resources...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Early in your post, you said, *...can Prolog somehow give a result that `likes(X, green)` is true for all X-es?*, but then you later say, *I don't want to ask, whether everyone likes green*, which seems to contradict the first question. The answer to the question, *Can you make new rules based on the facts available?* is "yes" if you make those rules yourself. That's what Prolog is about. But are you looking for some kind of automatic rule generation? If that were the case, then you'd need meta-rules to describe what a valid rule looks like.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for automatic rule generation. The idea is that in a bigger database I would not myself recognise patterns like everyone likes green, it would take too much time to write a query about all the possible patterns. I want Prolog to create the rules "everyone likes green" and "females like pink" without me making a query about each of those rules explicitly. Both of those rules should come up as a result to a single query.

Comment: It sounds like you want some "meta rules" to generate rules, which would be possible. But you'd need to write the meta rules. Then, per the answer given by @g_a_kowalski, you can use `assert/1`, etc, to manage dynamic rules.

Comment: I hoped that there would be an easier way, however if I want to make meta-rules instead of the usual `likes(X, green)`, which only asks if **anybody** likes green I need, a different query which asks if **everyone** likes green. Is that possible?

Comment: For meta rules to work relationships would need to be treated like variables. Something like `X(albert, pink). X=likes` however that doesn't work that way.

Comment: Ah I see... I think... I added an answer showing an example `everyone_likes` predicate.

Comment: I have since realised that I can solve the previous problem by defining relationships differently: `relationship(likes, albert, pink). ?relationship(X, albert, pink).  X=likes`. This way I can check if any relationship can be made into a rule without defining the meta-rule for each one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if *everyone* likes green, then you just need to define what *everyone* means. Let's suppose it means "all the males and females". Then you could do this:

```
everyone_likes(Color) :-
    everyone(Everyone),
    all_likes(Everyone, Color).

everyone(Everyone) :-
    findall(E, (male(E) ; female(E)), Everyone).

all_likes([Person|People], Color) :-
    likes(Person, Color),
    all_likes(People, Color).
all_likes([], _).
```

**Option 2**

An alternative to the above is to think about the logic in the negative. If *everyone likes green*, that is the opposite of *someone doesn't like green*. Expressing that in Prolog:

```
everyone_likes(Color) :-
    is_color(Color),
    \+ (  (male(P) ; female(P)),
          \+ likes(P, Color)
       ).
```

Rather than having to define who `everyone` is in this version, we need an `is_color` fact and/or predicate which defines a valid color (if we want the `everyone_likes(X)` query to work). This could be define simply as:

```
is_color(pink).
is_color(green).
is_color(orange).
...
```

Or, you could define it as a predicate which derives the choices of color from other facts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make new rules based on the facts available but I would suspect that it's very dependent on specific Prolog implementation. If you're working on SWI-Prolog, you can look at chapter 4.13 ("Database") in documentation and see how to use constructing predicates: assert/1, clause/2, clause/3 and others. It might be helpful to see description for copy_predicate_clauses/2.